# How to move blogs from BlogSpot to my own domain without harming SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, blog, blogspot

I am website (riddles) `http://example.blogspot.com/`
and the solution site `http://example2.blogspot.com`

To my bad i created 2 blogs. Now I am planning to move these 2 blogs into a single site (say example.com).

What can be my approach without impacting SEO?

Example

**`example.blogspot.com/2017/06/deduce-direction-puzzle.html`**

and

**`example2.blogspot.com/2017/06/deduce-direction-puzzle.html`**

should now point to same page of new website say 
**`example.com/deduce-direction-puzzle.html`**

Comment: Reason for -1 ?

Comment: Three people voted to close this as off-topic because it was specific to your site.   Now that it has been edited to use example domain names, it should be applicable to other people in similar situations.

Comment: Is your "new website" (ie. `example.com`) also hosted by Blogger, or is it an entirely separate website?

Comment: @DocRoot "new website will host on hostgator"

Comment: Only one blog you can migrate to example.com. If you migrate your other blog on subdomain like blog.example.com then it will create duplicate content issue. How about deleting one?